# $A_M$ integrally closed for all maximal ideals $M$ implies $A$ is integrally closed proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain. I am trying to understand a line in the following proof that $A_M$ integrally closed for all maximal ideals $M$ of $A$ implies $A$ is integrally closed, given by Vakil in his algebraic geometry notes.

Suppose $A$ is not integrally closed. We would like to show that there is some $M$ such that $A_M$ is not integrally closed. Suppose $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0$ (with $a_i\in A$ has a solution $s$ in $K(A)-A$ (where $K(A)$ is the fraction field for $A$). Let $I$ be the ideal $I:=\{r\in A\mid rs\in A\}$. Now, $I\neq A$, as $1\not\in I$. Thus there is some maximal ideal $M$ containing $I$.

The next sentence is "Then $s\not\in A_m$." Why does this follow from the above?

(I understand that questions about this theorem have been asked before, but I want to know specifically why this line follows from the above reasoning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $s\in A_M$. Then $s=a/b$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in A\setminus M$. But this implies $b\in I\subseteq M$, a contradiction.